# ImportError: opencv

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

i have recently updated to ubuntu 16.04 now after recompiling opencv i am facing an error.

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK2cv9Algorithm9paramHelpERKSs
```

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: which package do you mean

Comment: Show your complete code please

Comment: https://gist.github.com/arthurbeggs/06df46af94af7f261513934e56103b30/